# Advice needed: What and how to removeNulls (I'm not sure exactly what to do)

Tags: java, database, data-structures, removeclass

I have a practice question from lectures which I am not sure how to solve and would appreciate insight into what should be done and an explanation:

> Q: Give code for the method removeNulls(q) which removes from the Queue q all null elements. The method main contains a simple example illustrating the effect of method removeNulls.

```
    package labsSGTsCoursework.cw1;
     import net.datastructures.NodeQueue;
     import net.datastructures.Queue;
     public class CW1_q4 {
        public static <E> void removeNulls( Queue<E> q) {
             ... // YOUR CODE REPLACES DOTS HERE
}
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           // test method removeNulls
           Queue<Integer> que = new NodeQueue<Integer>();
           que.enqueue(5);
           que.enqueue(null);
           que.enqueue(8);
           que.enqueue(2);
           que.enqueue(null);
           System.out.println(que); // should print: "(5, null, 8, 2, null)"
           removeNulls(que);
           System.out.println(que); // should print: "(5, 8, 2)"
         }
}
```

Comment: Iterate over the `Queue`...?

Comment: What about   Iterator<E> , E next() returns next element in iteration,remove()  ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not notice it was a generic, so the markers approach will not work (thought is is a usefull trick sometimes so I leave it below).

Inside the method, make a new queue, copy all non null values from the old one to new, and then back to the original queue (as the values are consumed from orginal so you need to put them back).

For not, generic methods, the marker approach may work (as long as some values can never appearch in the input):
Insert a marker for example Integer.MAX_VALUE, iterate over the que and insert back all the elements which are not null, stop once you encounter your marker.